# How to fill every PageViewer's Tab with different data in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to instantiate a new fragment on every tab, and change the content of it from an array.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = CustomPageViewerFragment.newInstance(position);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rest_id.length;
    }
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.9f;
    }
}
```

Inside my `CustomPageViewerFragment` I declare every view and set the data from an array depending on position(i debugged and the position is right) The problem is that it fills the data wrong.

I tried `instantiateItem` method, but the views has to be added programmatically, and it is not my case.

How do I make the fragment reistantiate every time, so that it does not show the the data from last filled tab on all tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your Fragments before initializing your Adapter:

1. Create an Array or ArrayList of Fragments outside your Adapter
2. Fill that array with your desired Fragments
3. Pass the array to the Adapter
4. Get Fragment in getItem() using the `position` variable
5. Return that Fragment.

Comment: looks like a plan) trying it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> you have to add this,

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment f = null;

    switch (pos) {
    case 0:
        f = FirstFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    case 1:
        f = SecondFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    }
    return f;
}
```

> try this one....

Comment: That's what I am doing now, as a fast solution, but I need different number of pages every time, as I fill the data from an array from server.